# Saving an attachment in Mutt - how to select a directory using the list view

Tags: mutt, neomutt

I want to save an attachment to directory `~/a/b/c`. I can manually type in (tab complete etc) the path upon entering `~/a/b/c/` and mutt prompts to save. Fine.

But how can I achieve the same thing using the directory listings view?

I navigate to `~/a/b/c` which contains directory `d` and numerous files. How do I *select* `c` and not open it to view the listing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browse to the directory `~/a/b/c` and then use `N` to save as a new file in that directory.

You can then either type a file name, or if you want to save under the name that the attachment has, simply hit return: You'll be prompted "File ... is a directory, save under it?" which defaults to `yes`, so you can hit return again. Then `mutt` offers to save as `~/a/b/c/name_of_attachment`

Comment: Many thanks. I now interpret the `N           select-new           select a new file in this directory` under help correctly.